# append text to section in a XML file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a configuration file (xml) in Linux, I am trying to add additional   student to the student_names Configuration_item (if its not there)
For example if I get **Donald** I don't need to do anything because its there
If I get **Tom** I need to add it because its not there

```
<Configuration_item Key="foo" Value="bar"/>
<Configuration_item Key="students_names" Value="Todd;Marry;Alen;Donald"/>
<Configuration_item Key="foo2" Value="baz/>
```

Comment: Use a XML parser

Comment: That is an overkill for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to go on with a `XML` parser, however `bash` can do this in case the `xml` file is simple. Not a nice solution but it can do the trick.

```
#!/bin/bash

infile="$1"
name="$2"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  case $line in
    *students_names*) 
                      case $line in
                        *"$name"\;*|*"$name"\"*) echo "$line" ;;
                        *) echo "${line//Value=\"/Value=\"$name;}" ;;
                      esac ;;
    *) echo "$line" ;;
  esac
done < "$infile"
```

The script reads and parses the input `example.xml` file line by line. It applies variable expansion to match the target line (that contains `Key="students_names"`) and to decide whether it contains `$name`. If there is no match with `$name` then add it, else print the line.

***Example 1***:

`./add_value.sh example.xml Todd`

***Output***:

```
<Configuration_item Key="foo" Value="bar"/>
<Configuration_item Key="students_names" Value="Todd;Marry;Alen;Donald"/>
<Configuration_item Key="foo2" Value="baz/>
```

***Example 2***:

`./add_value.sh example.xml Toddy`

***Output***:

```
<Configuration_item Key="foo" Value="bar"/>
<Configuration_item Key="students_names" Value="Toddy;Todd;Marry;Alen;Donald"/>
<Configuration_item Key="foo2" Value="baz/>
```

Comment: thank you, what is this doing?  *"$name"\;*|*"$name"\"*)  is it like "Toddy  or Toddy" ?

Comment: It checks if $name in the $line string is followed by ; (name is in the middle of the listing) or “ (name is at the end of the listing). That is Toddy and Todd are different names this way. If there is a name that is substring of another name, it handles separately.